# change bin size of histogram data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have data from an SQL statement like

```
'select action_count, count(*) "num_users" from customers group by action_count;'
```

and load this into a pandas data frame. I can run a simple plot command on the data, or *barplot* it to make it look like a histogram. But how can I easily change the bin size of this data set? And how do I then plot the bins, i.e. the x-axis correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the location of the edges of bins using a list in `pandas` `hist`. For example, using a custom sequence with bin from `-2.0` to `-0.5` and then `-0.5` to `0.0` followed by a few increments of `0.1`,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df =pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.randn(10000)})
df.hist(bins=[-2.,-0.5,0.,0.1,0.2,0.3])   
plt.show()
```

which plots,

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is the normal way I know. But the data I have is not the raw data anymore (see SQL statement). It's like I were to write in your example `[((-2,-.5),2700), ((-.5,0), 1900), ...]` . Just that I have only integer numbers as 'bins'.

Comment: So you already have histogrammed data (e.g. like the output from `numpy.histogram`)? Do you want the plotted bar width to match these (in which case you could use the `width` argument to bar with an array as above). Or do you need to get different widths from the data you have (some form of interpolation)? Could you include some example data and maybe a sketch of the output?